# How to see hula dance in Hawaii

Tags: hawaii, maui

I'm planning to go to Hawaii and I want to see the famous hula dance.
Someone know where can I go?

Comment: Why was this closed?  It's pretty clear that the question is asking for where to do a specific activity (viewing hula dancing) in a pretty specific location (Maui).  It really doesn't seem sufficiently broad that it should be closed because ["we're not travel agents."](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been to the [Polynesian Cultural Center](http://www.polynesia.com/) and it was excellent. Not only do they cover Hawaiian culture, but they also cover the different cultures from a variety of different Polynesian islands. They certainly do the hula as well as a variety of other dances and performances.

Answer (score 1):

Most every luau offered in Hawaii features hula dancing as part of the entertainment during dinner.  You will find luaus offered most nights of the week on Maui and Hawai'i.

As Greg mentioned the Polynesian Cultural Center has hula demopnstrations.

But if you really want to see hula, you need to plan your trip for the week after Easter and attend the [Merrie Monarch Festival](http://merriemonarch.com/drupal/index.php) in Hilo.  This is THE hula competition, with dance teams coming from all over the islands and beyond.